# How to update Image in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm a newbie in vue, I need help to update image, I'm using `vform`, in below `onFileSelected` function responsible creating and updating image, I'm successfully creating data with image, but now I'm stack in update the image, here is my code with form structure

**Form**

```
<form @submit.prevent="editMode ? update() : store()">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="image" class="font-weight-bold">Image</label>
       <input class="form-control" type="file"
              :class="{ 'is-invalid': form.errors.has('image') }"
               name="image" id="image" accept="image/*"
               @change="onFileSelected">
       <has-error :form="form" field="image"></has-error>
   </div>
</form>
```

**I'm storing like this**

```
onFileSelected(event) {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    this.form.image = file;
 },

 store() {
    this.$Progress.start();
    this.form.busy = true;

    this.form.post('/api/students', {
          transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
          return objectToFormData(data)
        }],
      }).then(response => {
         //......
      }),
```

**My edit code is**

```
edit(student) {
    this.editMode = true;
    this.clearForm();
    this.form.fill(student);
    $('#modal').modal('show');
 },

 update() {
    this.$Progress.start();
    this.form.busy = true;
    this.form.patch('/api/students/' + this.form.id)
        .then(response => {


             //.........


             })
             .catch(e => {})
        },
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to include anything related to an image?

Comment: I updated my question in my question section. hope this will help @DelenaMalan

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that while your data is updating the render is not. For this you can put a `key` attribute (with some number or id) on the element that contains the image and then inside the update function once updated change the key like: `forceReloadKey++` this will force the component to rerender and update.
Like so:

```
<form :key="reloadKey" @submit.prevent="editMode ? update() : store()">
...
update() {
...
this.reloadKey++
...
```

Comment: Actually I'm new in this I don't get you can give some code.? @Michael